# "Cannot instantiate interface" but preference tag exists in di.xml

Tags: magento2, error, di, magento-2.1.10

I'm getting this error when trying to load a page:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface 
Codazon\ThemeOptions\Framework\App\Config\Scope\ReaderPoolInterface 
in /magento2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:73
```

but there is

```
<preference 
  for="Codazon\ThemeOptions\Framework\App\Config\Scope\ReaderPoolInterface" 
  type="Codazon\ThemeOptions\Model\Config\Reader\ReaderPool"/>
```

in `/magento2/app/code/Codazon/ThemeOptions/etc/di.xml`. The `type` file exists and looks good. This is a module for new theme.

I've already tried:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento cache:flush
rm -rf var/generation/* var/cache/* var/di/*
```

Magento version is 2.1.10. How can I fix/debug this?

Comment: How you use the interface?

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh it's injected into constructor in a class `/magento2/app/code/Codazon/ThemeOptions/Framework/App/Config/ScopePool.php` and implemented in `magento2/app/code/Codazon/ThemeOptions/Model/Config/Reader/ReaderPool.php`. Also, this module works on other installation where files are the same but the other install has less modules and is version 2.1.9 (this one is 2.1.10).

Comment: What deploy mode is currently set? You can check with the command `bin/magento deploy:mode:show`

Comment: @7ochem It's in developer mode. / Update: I've manually copied all modules to the other(working) installation and enabled them. Everything's still fine there. I've changed db(copy from the working install) and downgraded from Magento 2.1.10 to 2.1.9 on the broken install - still doesn't work.